# org.hibernate.MappingException: property mapping has wrong number of columns

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, many-to-one

I practice whit spring framework and database (PostgreSQL) and I got the tables whit IntelliJ ( Modules JPA ), and I have this exception when I try to run.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: property mapping has wrong number of columns: com.whoim.bootloader.entitys.TblConversation.tblUsersByCreatorIdConversation type: com.whoim.bootloader.entitys.TblUsers
```

I generate this code from persistence on IntelliJ ( Modules JPA ) and refactor whit Lombok

```java
package com.whoim.bootloader.entitys;

    import lombok.*;

    import javax.persistence.*;
    import java.sql.Timestamp;
    import java.util.Collection;

    @Data
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "tbl_conversation", schema = "public", catalog = "d1fu1ri15o3ia3")
    public class TblConversation {
        @Id@Column(name = "id_conversation")
        private int idConversation;
        @Basic@Column(name = "conversation_title")
        private String conversationTitle;
        @Basic@Column(name = "creator_id_conversation")
        private int creatorIdConversation;
        @Basic@Column(name = "conversation_channel_id")
        private String conversationChannelId;
        @Basic@Column(name = "conversation_created_at")
        private Timestamp conversationCreatedAt;
        @Basic@Column(name = "conversation_updated_at")
        private Timestamp conversationUpdatedAt;
        @Basic@Column(name = "conversation_deleted_at")
        private Timestamp conversationDeletedAt;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumns({
                @JoinColumn(name = "creator_id_conversation", referencedColumnName = "id_user", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true),
                @JoinColumn(name = "creator_id_conversation", referencedColumnName = "id_user", nullable = false)})
        private TblUsers tblUsersByCreatorIdConversation;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tblConversationByDeletedConversationsConversationId")
        private Collection<TblDeletedConversations> tblDeletedConversationsByIdConversation;
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tblConversationByConversationIdMessages")
        private Collection<TblMessages> tblMessagesByIdConversation;
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tblConversationByConversationIdParticipants")
        private Collection<TblParticipants> tblParticipantsByIdConversation;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your mapping should, as per standards, as follows:

```
    @Basic@Column(name = "creator_id_conversation", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private int creatorIdConversation;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "creator_id_conversation"
              , referencedColumnName = "id_user", nullable = false)})
    private TblUsers tblUsersByCreatorIdConversation;
```

Comment: thanks!... now its ok, sometimes solutions are so simple